# Join meta doesn't join main site automatically?

Tags: support, login, stackexchange.com

Now this account joined this site(meta), but when I move to Stackexchange.com, the page asks me to join the community, is it normal? if so, is it also apply to other sites?

(I remember this account joined the community from meta.stackexchange.com, but not from Stackexchange.com, now I visit stackexchange.com and still ask me to join the community, as if main and meta are different sites)

(I test again: login to meta.stackexchange.com with google successfully, then move to Stackexchange.com, but in Stackexchange.com I'm not logged in. When I login to Stackexchange.com again the site asks me to join the community, sorry I dun know how to capture screen and can only describe the story with words!)

Comment: Not sure if related but for the sake of completeness: In which browser do you see this?

Comment: Which site exactly are you seeing it ask you to join the community?  Can you identify exactly which site, and maybe post a screenshot?  Stackexchange.com doesn't show a "join this community" link, as far as I can see, so I'm confused and wondering if maybe you're asking about some other main site.

Comment: You should be auto logged in. As @D.W. said, something here is weird, please explain what exactly you see.

Comment: Which two+ URLs are you moving between, specifically?

Comment: You say "I visit stackexchange.com and still ask me to join the community" - please post screenshot, since this sounds impossible. (you should just see "login")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

stackexchange.com is not the main site for meta.stackexchange.com. It's a read-only portal of network activity.

Having said that yes, please post a screenshot if at all possible (use the snipping tool on Windows... I forget what the Mac keyboard shortcuts are). You *should* be automatically getting a user on stackexchange.com if you don't already have one but are logged in... or at least you should see a "log in" link rather than "join this community".